# plotting area plot as a subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way to have the df_HT.plot.area() as one of the subplots in my figure?
This is my code. I want to include an area plot as one of the subplots, but I can't find a way to do it.

```
HT_iso = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/HT_d13C.csv',header=0 )

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(20,12), sharey=True, gridspec_kw{'wspace':0} )
fig.suptitle('Horizontally stacked subplots')

ax1.plot(HT_iso['13C Bulk'], HT_iso['Depth (m)'])

df_HT.plot.area()

ax2.plot()

ax3.plot(HT_plt['dD_MotherWater'], HT_plt['depth (m)'],'-o')
ax3.invert_yaxis()

ax4.plot()

ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax3.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax4.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax4.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
```

Comment: Which subplot? Something like `df_HT.plot.area(ax=ax2)`?

Comment: Yes! That was it. Thank you